# Execution of a batch file not as expected in c#

Tags: c#, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file on c:\. When I execute it by double clicking it, All works fine.

All That the batch file does is this.

1) It executes a .exe on the same directory.
   2) Redirects the output to a text file in the same directory.

The .bat contains

```
   parse.exe > "temp.txt"
```

But, When I execute the batch file through C#, temp.txt is not created at all.(The batch file seems to run ofcourse.)

I used the following C# code.

```
             Process p = new Process();
             // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
             p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
             p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
             p.StartInfo.FileName = "c://resource//auto.bat";
             p.Start();

             // Read the output stream first and then wait.
             string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
             p.WaitForExit();
```

Where am I going Wrong ? 
Thanks in adv.

**Edit**

When I changed the batch file into something like this,

parse.exe > "c:\temp.txt" instead of parse.exe > "temp.txt"

a temp file is created. But, it doesnot contain the output of parse.exe.

Comment: `"c://resource//auto.bat"` is a strange path to give, by the way.

Comment: The lesson learnt: Always set a working directory when you are executing a process. Don't ever assume that the process(in my case,the batch file) itself knows its working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\";
```

you can also set absolute path in your batch file which will work immediately

pathofparse\parse.exe yourpath\"temp.txt";

Comment: Thanks Hassan for the input. But, how do I set the working directory to a folder inside my project. I have a folder "resource" inside my project at bin folder. Now, How do I set the working directory to that folder. I tried out, "..//resource//auto.bat" but it throwed me a exception,.

Comment: use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\resource" (if you have a resource folder in your bin or use directly Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: Yes, that was of great help! Setting the working directory of the process solved every issues. Marking this as the answer. Thanks Hassan!

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by using using fully qualified file names in your batch file, i.e.

c:\parse.exe > "c:\temp.txt"

Comment: Yes that works @Pierre. Thanks a lot. But, I cannot give an absolute path in my batch file. The batch file wherever it is should execute with parse.exe > temp.txt (I mean the relative path.) How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are redirecting the output, which could prevent the output going to the file you expected to be created.

Did you try it with `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false`?

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting the working directory. The file may be being created, just not in the spot you think.  It is worth a try ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write output to the directory that contains your batch file, you're better off specifying the directory explicitly, e.g.:

```
parse.exe > "%~dp0temp.txt"
```